# Coding sigma formula?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python beginner, running 2.7

I cannot find a Pythonic way to code the following formula. My goal is to have a single function into which I can input the values (in previous attempts I've only found a highly repetitive brute-force solution).

[image: formula]

**Necessary information**:

if you don't know what the sigma symbol means: [look here](http://mathlesstraveled.com/appendices/sigma-notation/)

```
# 'v' is the formula
# 'i' 'j' 'k' are actors with numerical attributes 'c' 's' and 'x'
# 'n' = length of the following lists (length is identical for all four lists)

values_1 = [Bob, Sue, Mary, Jo...] # i, j, and k are any 3 values drawn from this list  
                        # under the condition that i != j != k

values_2 = [5,6,7,8...] # c is drawn from this list. 
                        # if i = values_1[0], then c(i) = values_2[0]. 
                        # same for j and k

values_3 = [9,10,11,12...] # s is drawn from this list.  
                        # if i = values_1[0], then s(i) = values_3[0]

values_4 = [13,14,15, 16..] # x is drawn from this list. 
                           # if i = values_1[0], then x(i) = values_4[0].

def V (j,k):
        #this is where I need help!

v_Bob_Sue = # this is where V(Bob, Sue) should go.
            # this is what the math would look like in English:
# SUM of (c_Mary * s_Mary * ((abs(x_Mary - x_Sue) - abs(x_Mary - x_Bob)) / x's range))
# and (c_Jo * s_Jo * ((abs(x_Jo - x_Sue) - abs(x_Jo - x_Bob)) / x's range))

# Bob and Sue are the j and k value
# we do the formula with all the other actors (from values_1) who AREN'T Bob and Sue


v_Bob_Mary = # etc 
v_Bob_Jo = 
v_Sue_Bob =
v_Sue_Mary =
v_Sue_Jo =
v_Mary_Bob =
v_Mary_Sue =
v_Mary_Jo =
v_Jo_Bob =
v_Jo_Sue =
v_Jo_Mary =
```

Comment: i am assuming that this formula is something which is known by some name, can you link the name of the formula/websites about it, so i can understand the process that has to happen inside of it?

Comment: The math represents a process called 'pairwise voting.' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison The specific formula is from a research paper in a for-pay academic journal. I am not sure if it is ok to post copyrighted IP on StackOverflow?

Comment: well, can you explain the mathematical notation in your question then?

Comment: OK, adding it into the post now.

Comment: first of all have you tried using a dictionary instead of multiple lists whose indexes are the same? (for example: `{'Bob': [5,9,13], 'Sue': [6,10,14],...}` ??

Comment: also, how exactly do you want to compare them to each other?

Comment: No, I haven't. That's a good idea. However, I am not sure if it would help my major problem: how to code the sigma symbol. i.e. how to keep the same j and k values, run many different i values, and sum the results?

Answer (score 11):

As for the "sigma", computation is pretty easy as it is also called a "sum". There is a built-in function for this in python : http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum

As for the formula you provide, I think that what you really miss here are lists or arrays. i, j and k can be indices of n-dimensional arrays.
I would use the numpy package for this :

```
import numpy as np

c = np.asarray(values_2)
s = np.asarray(values_3)
x = np.asarray(values_4)

def V(j, k):
    return np.sum(c * s * (np.abs(x - x[j]) - np.abs(x - x[k])) / np.abs(x[-1] - x[0]))
```

Here Bob and Sue are encoded by there indice position in the values_1 list. This makes it way easier than working with strings or class instances. So you would write :

```
v_Bob_Sue = V(0, 1)
```

If you want to automagically create the variables v_Bob_Sue and such you need to define variable names dynamically. So you need the exec statment as follows :

```
for i in xrange(len(values_1)):
    for j in xrange(len(values_1)):
        exec("v_%s_%s = V(%u, %u)" % (values_1[i], values_1[j], i, j)
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will download numpy and try it. Thanks. Small correction to your last code block: the variable name 'v_Bob_Sue' represents v_j_k, not v_i_j (as you coded it). The logic of your code makes total sense though and I will try that as well, thanks.

Comment: I think it's probably not a good idea to create those variables like that. I think the "right" way to do this is to just do this as a broadcast operation of some sort. Maybe a 3D matrix that sums down to a 2D matrix.

Answer (score -1):

Using python 3.6.x, you could try...

```
def sigma(lowerBound, upperBound):
    x = list(range(lowerBound, upperBound))
    print(" + ".join(str(i) for i in x) + " = " + str(sum(x)))

sigma(0, 10)

# output
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question posed (which, by the way, was asked 6 years ago, and already has a quality answer).